# Usage of Dynamic Allocation

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Coming from Java and C#, I'm used to doing the following:

```
byte[] myArray = new byte[10];
```

and not caring about having to clean it up.  However, now that I'm using C++, you obviously have to be careful about allocation and memory leaks.

I've heard some people say that you should avoid dynamic allocation *at all costs*, but I've also seen some people use it 'liberally', using the `new` operator to instantiate classes when a local stack variable would have sufficed:

```
DatabaseConnection conn = new DatabaseConnection("127.0.0.1");
// or
DatabaseConnection conn("127.0.0.1");
```

I'm aware that arrays allocated  on the heap are much slower, but I would favor more readable and extensible code over a small performance hit that may occur as a result of using dynamic memory.

So, my question is: is it true that you should avoid heap allocation at all costs?

Comment: "but I've also seen some people use it 'liberally', using the new operator to instantiate classes when a local stack variable would have sufficed" => those people probably don't know what they are doing. For this specific case, use `std::vector<byte>` (without any `new`).

Comment: If I could upvote ^ this, more than once, I would.

Comment: And you don't have to worry about it nearly as much if you use RAII instead of `new/delete`.

Comment: Sometimes you have no choice - if you want to return something from a function, if you don't allocate it on the heap it will disappear immediately.

Comment: Also, if ever really need to allocate on the heap (say you need a pointer) use smart ptrs

Comment: @krsteeve, Return it by value.

Comment: @krsteeve, And smart pointers can do that, too, so you should still use them :)

Comment: @chris *shudder* smart pointers. Another tool to prevent people from actually learning C++

Comment: @krsteeve, Umm, smart pointers *are* C++. Code that doesn't use them and uses `new/delete` instead is more like C.

Comment: @krsteeve I don't know what there is to learn by not using them. You might become good at using a debugger, but that is a side effect.

Comment: @krsteeve Don't tell me you're one of those "abstractions get in the way of learning" guys...

Comment: @krsteeve: Actually, you only need indirection for dynamic binding. It doesn't matter where the data sits. You could call a function with data in automatic memory and have it operate on the reference.

Comment: I agree 100% on using RAII. In this case vector. I just want to make clear that of course heap allocation will still take place. I think the question is also about heap allocation in itself disregard of abstraction.

Comment: I added an edit to elaborate more on the "liberal" use of `new`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that in this case, using this is fine:

```
byte myArray[10];
```

If you need an array you can copy (e.g. return from a function), then using `vector<byte>` is the right soluton.

The very last resort should be to use `new`, and only allocate small regions if the data needs to presist outside the function.

Unfortunately, books don't always tell you good practices, or shows good examples of when you should and shouldn't use, for example `new` - instead, they show things like `int *arr = new int[5];` - which probably takes up more space in overhead than the actual data.

And of course, all `new` must be `deleted`. Using smart pointers (`shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`) will help a lot by doing automatic cleanup.

Comment: `std::array<byte>` can also be copied.

Comment: This proposal is actually really bad. having maintained such code with buffer overflows. i recommend to never use it. Never use magic numbers like that.

Comment: @Frodo: But calling new and buffer overflowing doesn't work any better, does it? There are situations where buffers won't overflow, because the hardware or protocol determines the size - if the network card doesn't have more than 4 bytes in an IP address, then I shouldn't have to deal with a variable length array (e.g. vector) simply because of some rule that I can't use fixed size arrays. There are situations when you shouldn't use fixed size arrays too - no doubt. But forcing the use of one or another is not a good idea. (Of course, naming a constant instead of using 10 is a good idea!)

Comment: @Mats Petersson: yes you are correct. But fix allocations is often a quick fix which will later be costly. It was used a lot before we had STL.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever possible? Yes. At all costs? No. Dynamic allocation is, very often, the simplest solution to a problem.

However, *do* avoid using `new` at virtually all costs. Rely on `make_shared` and `make_unique` to produce single objects, and containers like `std::vector` for more than one. There is no excuse for you to ever use `delete`.

Comment: @nijansen, Yes, it is, but you can make your own in C++11, and C++14 is coming fairly soon :)

Comment: @nijansen It was an oversight in C++11 and IIRC, it's relatively easy to implement your own or carefully wrap any necessary `new` call in the `unique_ptr` constructor.

Comment: @nijansen That is no excuse for bad code. The underlying ideas of those constructs are what matters. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true, you should avoid heap allocations whenever possible. In the case you mentioned, you should use containers provided by the standard library, like `std::vector<byte>`, as suggested in the comments.

If you absolutely must store something on the heap, use RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization), meaning an object (on the stack) that performs acquisition when constructed, and releases the resource when destructed. Since C++11 there is `std::unique_ptr` for this, or the more sophisticated `std::shared_ptr` (together with `std::weak_ptr`), if you need multiple owners of a resource:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> unique(new int(42));
auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
```

If you cannot use C++11 yet, almost every library will provide you with some kind of smartpointer - boost gives you `scoped_ptr`/`scoped_array`, `shared_ptr`/`shared_array`, `weak_ptr`, and `intrusive_ptr`; Poco gives you `AutoPtr`, etc. There is even a smartpointer in C++03, the `auto_ptr`, but I strongly discourage from using that one; its use is now deprecated, and it has really weird copying behavior, because C++03 does not support rvalue references / move semantics.

Comment: I don't think Boost has `unique_ptr`, unless it's some kind of recent addition.

Answer (score 1):

You can always approach such questions from two vectors; Maintainability/Readability and Performance. Sometimes the second is important, sometimes not. Sometimes you don't care about the first. However, in this case, I'd say that putting stuff as much as possible on automatic memory ("stack") versus dynamic memory ("heap") wins in both points (most of the time).

Allocating dynamic memory is just so slow compared to changing the stack pointer, there can hardly be an argument regarding performance. But if you allocate stuff that doesn't leave its scope in dynamic memory, you have to take care to release the memory after the scope, if you forget, you are *not only leaking memory, you are likely breaking correctness because the destructors are not called*. It's less maintainable in that regard.

It helps to be sceptical about every single `new` and consider it smelly. It prevents you from unnecessarily overdoing it.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with dynamic allocations:

1. Memory leaks (if you forget to delete the object)
2. High number of alloc/free requests - stack allocations on the other hand simply moves the stack pointer once when function is called. Some automatic variables may even reside in registers without taking up memory.
3. Heap fragmentation.

Basically, only use heap if you exhausted all other options.

Comment: Not when using std::vector to do the job, but I am sure you just did not write that.